# Get nested data from Firestore Database in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using reactJS to create a simple social media app. This is the schema of my database:

```
--- posts (collection)
         |
         --- uid (documents)
              |
              --- userPosts (collection)
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
                    |     |
                    |     --- title: "Post Title"
                    |     |
                    |     --- date: September 03, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
                          |
                          --- title: "Post Title"
```

I would like posts to be refreshed in real time with onSnapshot method. How to get ALL of my posts?
I changed the structure of my database like you see and I don't know how to get my posts that are nested.
This is how I did it before when all of my posts were in "posts" collection.

```
const [posts,setPosts]= useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
            setPosts(
                snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({
                  id: doc.id,
                  post : doc.data()
                })));
        })
     }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the nested posts by providing the path to it, like this:

```
const [posts,setPosts]= useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
           snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({
             doc.collection('userPosts').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
               setPosts(
                 snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({
                   id: doc.id,
                   post : doc.data()
               })));
             });
           }));
        });
     }, []);
```

Comment: But the problem is that it is not a 'uid' but it is a uid of the user. There are many different uids there because every user can post.

Comment: @dodododo97 If you want **ALL Posts** of a single user, you can put the _uid of the user_  in place  of  'uid'. And If you want **ALL Posts of ALL Users**, then check the code I've just updated.